# How to cut out substrings (paths) of a URL in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to cut out substrings from this url *XYZ.com/de/haus/dach/* and put the values each in its own columns in Google Spreadsheet.

With this url example:

- Column A should be "de"
- Column B should be "haus"
- Column C should be "dach"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the characters before the first `/`. This can be done in a number of ways, including [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) or through a combination of [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625), [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) and [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625).
2. [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) the resulting string.

```
=SPLIT(RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-(FIND("/",A1)))),"/")
```

[image]

Comment: @lamblichus Extended question: How can I do the same when there are "-" into the names? Example: https://www.XY.com/de/haus/dach-ziegel-stein//

Then it shoul be 
- Column A >haus
- Column B > dach
- Column C > Ziegel
- Column D > Stein

Comment: @johny Consider posting a new question for this.

Comment: Ok I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994448/cut-out-substrings-of-an-url-in-google-spreadsheets-with-different-characters